# PHP PDO Insert Only Inserting First Character

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP & PDO to insert results from an API into a mysql DB (innodb). Here is my code to do this:

```
 $insertbrewery = $db->prepare('insert into breweries values(DEFAULT, :api_id, :name, :city, :state, DEFAULT)');

foreach ($data as $result) {

$insertbrewery->bindParam('api_id', $id);
$insertbrewery->bindParam('name', $result[brewery][name]);
$insertbrewery->bindParam('city', $result[brewery][locality]);
$insertbrewery->bindParam('state', $result[brewery][region]);

$insertbrewery->execute();

if ($insertbrewery) {
  echo $insertbrewery->rowcount()." breweries successfully submitted.<br />";

} else {
  echo "An error occurred with submitting the post to the database. Sorry.";
}

}
```

Comment: What is `$result`?  Show us `var_dump($result);`.  Why aren't you quoting your keys?  Try: `$result['brewery']['name']`

Comment: Can you tell us more? Such as your expected output vs. the actual output?

Comment: maybe the the database->table-> field (probably varchar) is configured as length = 1 ?

Comment: `bindParam('api_id', $id);` should be `bindParam(':api_id', $id);` you missed `:`

Comment: Tried quoting keys and it did not do anything different.

Comment: Got it, Cengiz was right, the first 2 field lengths were 1 (d'oh) and then adding the colons to the bindparam names fixed the rest, thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parameter names are `:name`, `:city` and `:state` (leading colon included). Also, be sure to quote your keys in your arrays.

Change this:

```
$insertbrewery->bindParam('name', $result[brewery][name]);
$insertbrewery->bindParam('city', $result[brewery][locality]);
$insertbrewery->bindParam('state', $result[brewery][region]);
```

To this:

```
$insertbrewery->bindParam(':name', $result['brewery']['name']);
$insertbrewery->bindParam(':city', $result['brewery']['locality']);
$insertbrewery->bindParam(':state', $result['brewery']['region']);
```

Comment: Thank you! Will select this as correct answer once I can (6 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

Bad array syntax:

```
$insertbrewery->bindParam('name', $result[brewery][name]);
$insertbrewery->bindParam('city', $result[brewery][locality]);
$insertbrewery->bindParam('state', $result[brewery][region]);
```

Should be:

```
$insertbrewery->bindParam('name', $result['brewery']['name']);
$insertbrewery->bindParam('city', $result['brewery']['locality']);
$insertbrewery->bindParam('state', $result['brewery']['region']);
```

Comment: but I think this is not solves current problem which is missed `:`

Comment: The original code would generate an E_NOTICE, but would result in the same logic (assuming those constants are undefined).